# Generate SOAP requests on the fly, based on WSDL

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'd like to build a simple test harness for the various web services consumed by my application that I can run in my staging or production environment to verify that the web services are working and see what data their web methods are returning.

Is there a way I can generate a SOAP request based on the WSDL provided by a web service at run time (i.e. without adding a web reference to my project and creating a proxy for the web service)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out SoapUI (http://www.soapui.org/).  It's the only tool I've ever needed for testing Web Services.

Comment: Thanks Chad, SoapUI looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html).